# Vim E78 Unknown mark. When Im triying to map

Tags: dictionary, vim

So I wrote this line on my .vimrc:

```
nnoremap ,, mtA;<Esc>`<space>t
```

If I do it by myself everything is allright, but if I use the mapp (,,) It tells me that is a unknown mark. Any idea?

Comment: I think you want `\`t`, without that "<space>" in between the two characters, no? It's complaining that "space" is not a valid mark. You saved "t", so I guess that's what you wanted, right?

Comment: Its a dead key, When I jump to a mark I have to press that space so I guess Vim has to as well. As I said this does work If I do it, but obiously I want Vim to do it for me

Comment: But not in a mapping! In a mapping you're already typing backquote-space yo enter the backquote, right? That's when the deadkey effect happens. Remove the `<space>` and this will work.

Comment: You are right I tough vim work strictly literally,  thanks you. Write it as an answer so I can upvote you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the `<space>` you have in between `` ` `` and `t` to restore the `` `t `` mark.

In the comments you mentioned that `` ` `` is a dead key in your keyboard layout, but that doesn't really play a part in a mapping expansion, since in a way you're already typing `` ` `` followed by a "space" to enter a literal `` ` `` in the mapping expansion.

Fix it by removing the `<space>`:

```
nnoremap ,, mtA;<Esc>`t
```